# Using same .htaccess in different environments

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

From development to testing to production our website resides in three different environments

- http: //localhost/version/
- http: //www.production.com/test/
- http: //www.production.com/

(see examples of URLs in the following .htaccess snippet)

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^brand/(.+) /products.php?brand=$1 [R,NC]
RewriteRule ^product/(.+) /products.php?model=$1 [R,NC]
```

How do I capture that first part of the URL and prepend it in the .htaccess file, so that the following URLs all behave the same:

- http: //localhost/version/product/c20
- http: //www.production.com/test/product/c20
- http: //www.production.com/product/c20

I've looked at RewriteCond, but haven't found out how I can use it in this case. Enlighten me, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** This seems to work:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/(brand|product)/
RewriteRule ^brand/(.+) %1/x.php?brand=$1 [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/(brand|product)/
RewriteRule ^product/(.+) %1/x.php?model=$1 [NC]
```

Comment: This prepends the physical path. Something like this

   http: //localhost/C:/wamp/www/version/product.php?model=c20

Comment: Edited with a tested solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could set that part optional:

```
RewriteRule ^(version/|test/)?brand/(.+) /$1products.php?brand=$2 [R,NC]
RewriteRule ^(version/|test/)?product/(.+) /$1products.php?model=$2 [R,NC]
```